# ASP.NET MVC Memory Usage Inspection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on a large asp.net mvc 5 web application using SQl Server / LINQ to SQL (deployed on Azure if that helps).

It has a lot of functionalities, memory caching, session usage and so on.. Obviously it ends up using a lot of memory.

What are the best options to first investigate with the purpose of reducing the used memory?

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Memory Leaks in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274566/detecting-memory-leaks-in-asp-net)

Comment: the post and most responses there are from 6 years ago, i was hoping for something newer :)