# Asp.net application crash on live server while we working on it, on restart IIS it working again

Tags: asp.net, iis

My asp.net application crashes sometimes in live server while we are working on it. All users are facing [Exceptions]yellow error screen.And Throws dozens of exception in exception log.

> [Get] find 0 Table rows

This exception occurs on randomly not on specific location or specific click.
But when I restart my application on IIS the application working fine. but again some hours same problem appears.

When I try to Re-login Than application don't find my credentials. but after restart IIS. I successfully login in to application with same credentials.

Summary: not find the specific reason of crashes. Working fine when i restart IIS.

> 1. drop down list are not find data from datasource
> 2. Grid table find 0 rows when access to table.

when same grid and drop down list is access after IIS restart it has data.

> Note: its feels that we lost connection from database. but actually it
>   has connection but find no data in it

Comment: What exactly is the exception message/stack trace?

Comment: Steve its give dozens of exceptions. but i share it with you some exceptions
innerException====>System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.

Comment: Define "while we are working on it". What exactly do you do when it crashes?

Comment: This exception occurs on randomly not on specific location or specific click.

Comment: Why do you say _"while we are working on it"_? This implies development being done on a live server. Or do you simply mean _"while users are using the site"_?

Comment: while we using the application. mean my user use application,

Comment: CRUD operations

Comment: With exception call stacks and the source code, your top priority is to understand them and fix the code. If you are not capable of doing so, I suggest you open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to consult Microsoft. It would be hard for SO to help, as no one here has access to your code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search i find the depth of the problem and the problem is memory leak.

> Memory leaks in .NET applications have always been a programmer’s
>   nightmare. Memory leaks is the biggest problems when it comes to
>   production servers. Productions servers normally need to run with the
>   least down time. Memory leaks grow slowly and after sometime they
>   bring down the server by consuming huge chunks of memory. Most of the
>   time people reboot the system, make it work temporarily, and send a
>   sorry note to the customer for the downtime

some use full links are:
    [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274566/detecting-memory-leaks-in-asp-net)
[link 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42721/Best-Practices-No-5-Detecting-NET-application-memo)

The proper solution of the problem is very time consuming and need a skill full person.
 Solution for temporary basis is when you application is down you need to reset ISS programatically.

> Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisreset.exe", "/noforce");

or

> Process p = new Process(); p.StartInfo = new
>   ProcessStartInfo("iisreset.exe"); p.Start();

I know this is not a good solution but this can put the pressure off from your head.

For proper solution check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274566/detecting-memory-leaks-in-asp-net?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch exception and check server response time

Comment: when ever server crash its ADD 100 hundreds of exception in excretion log.which exception i take.